# How can a fragment be in the whole activity_main layout?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a fragment view in my activity main layout, but i can´t put it on the whole layout, I have also bottom mobile navigation, but the problem is at the top of the layout.

With an image is better:
[activity_main.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVrdl.png)

The code of that layout is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

How can I fix that? In the fragment I have a recyclerview

Comment: Remove the top padding that you put: `android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Your `constraintlayout`
Remove this Attribute

```
android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

your fragment get full layout size.

Answer (score 0):

Just use LinearLayout with <fragment height=0dp weight=1<fragment